# Bloomberg Terminal Screener for HQ Location with Revenue Sort

Tags: business-intelligence, analysis, bloomberg, financial

How do I build a screener for the Bloomberg Terminal that let's me identify a list of headquarters by state and sort by revenue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either EQS GO or PSCR GO function. Then just select specific headquarters you're interested in within the criteria section and sort by revenue. If you use private companies as well (PSCR) the revenue detail will be less clear.

Comment: Thank you! These two functions created the screens I needed for my analysis.

Comment: Can you mark it answered then so others struggling with the same question see it answered?